# How to write the Path of a file to upload in a text box?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

Little question: I'm trying to create a Form to upload a file.

Now i got a button to select the file and a submit button.

How can i design it like if i've selected a file, the path of it (C:\Users....) is shown in a textbox?`

Thx for help

Comment: Do you mean copy the file path into different, separate textbox in addition to the input control itself?

Comment: Yes, like this. Watch the comment of mine in David Dorwards answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To copy the selected file name/path to different text box, first have this JS:

```
function CopyMe(oFileInput, sTargetID) {
    document.getElementById(sTargetID).value = oFileInput.value;
}
```

And it will work with such HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="file" onchange="CopyMe(this, 'txtFileName');" />
</div>
<div>
    You chose: <input id="txtFileName" type="text" readonly="readonly" />
</div>
```

Test case: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/gP7Bz/

Note that modern browsers will hide the real full path showing something like `C:\fakepath\realname.txt` so to show only the name (which is real) change to:

```
function CopyMe(oFileInput, sTargetID) {
    var arrTemp = oFileInput.value.split('\\');
    document.getElementById(sTargetID).value = arrTemp[arrTemp.length - 1];
}
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/gP7Bz/1/)

Comment: Wow, really nice! This is exactly what i've been looking for! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Florian Cheers, though can't really understand what you need it for.. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upload a file, use `<input type="file" …>` and it will come with it's own button. Don't forget to set the [enctype](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-enctype).

A regular text box won't let you upload files.

Comment: yes, i know, but i thought, <input type="file"> is a button, and if i select with this one a file, the path of it will be shown in a textfield. This is much more user-friendly

Comment: By default, most browsers display `<input type="file">` as a widget consisting of a text box and a button … which is what it sounds like you want. So what is the problem?

Comment: Chrome show the selected file as "label", looks like the OP want it inside a textbox in addition. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `<input type="file"..>` will not show textbox in chrome and safri browser, we can configure the display styles by CSS itself, go to the link [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html)